# Does Aegis Augment Weapon suit option affect ranged weapons they use?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, psionics, ranged-attack

Does Aegis Augment Weapon suit option affect ranged weapons they use?

> **Augmented Weapon**
>
> The astral suit coats the aegis’s weapon. The weapon is treated as if it was one size category larger for damage purposes. The aegis does not suffer any penalties for wielding the weapon. This ability does not stack with effects that increase the aegis’s size category, such as expansion. The aegis must be at least 6th level to select this customization.

Will it work thrown weapons or weapons with launchers (Bow, X-bows & fire arms), or as soon as the weapon thrown or fired, it reverts back to its original size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Following only the RAW you've quoted, yes

> The weapon is treated as if it was one size category larger for damage purposes.

Its size is not augmented, as in the *Enlarge* spell. It is merely treated as if it was a size larger. So it can not decrease size once you let go of it.

There are other rulings relevant to effects affecting ranged and thrown weapons (conserving magical buffs when fired/thrown), such as the Bane property. So you can have ranged/thrown weapons enhanced by abilities.

Since there is no caveat regarding weapons (as the one you can find in the *Enlarge* spell), by RAW, it should work. When there is an exception, the rule states it.